# What is the breaking change in semver 2.0.0

Tags: semantic-versioning

There is a version [2.0.0](http://semver.org/spec/v2.0.0.html) of the semantic versioning spec, given that you should:

> increment the MAJOR version when you make incompatible API changes,

What was the incompatible change between semver 1.0.0 and 2.0.0?

Comment: Where is defined that the semver itself uses semantic versioning for its specification, which makes it possible to ask this quesiton?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I asked on the [semver github repo](https://github.com/mojombo/semver/issues/231). There are two changes that are not backwards compatible:

- leading zeros are not accepted
- minor version numbers MUST be incremented if API is marked as deprecated